# return a factorial of list numbers

Tags: list, recursion, lisp

I am trying to implement a function which when called return a factorial of  numbers in list. For example (fact '(2 4 3))  =>  (2 24 6) but mine is not working. I am pretty sure that the logic is correct for my implementation just I can not find my syntax error. So if you could have a look and give some feedback it would be great here is the code:

```
(defun fact (list)
    (cond ((null list) 0)
        ((zerop (first list) 1))
        (* first list(fact (rest list)))    
        ))
```

Comment: You will have to explain what "is not working" and how.

Comment: when i give a arguments in the function it is returning invalid number of arguments error

Comment: You're calling `zerop` with two arguments, it only accepts one. And you're using `first` as a variable when you probably want to use it as a function, i.e. `(first list)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you appear to be trying to do is apply a factorial function to each member of a list and collect the results in a list.

For this you need a factorial function and `mapcar`.